# How to override variables on Dart/flutter

Tags: variables, flutter, dart, syntax

I'm coming from TS/JS background and I was overriding properties using it previous value with something like this in **Javasctipt/Typesctipt**:

```js
let arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
arr = arr.filter( name => name != 'messi');

// results
// arr = ['mo salah'];
```

Now in **Dart**, I can't do that and I have searched through the docs/internet and didn't find useful answers for the right syntax!

What I did is same as above code:

```dart
var arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
arr = arr.where( (name) => name != 'messi' );

// results
nothing showing up
```

I have seen on some articles for creating a search with the dart that they clearing the `arr` first then adding the new filter arr:

```dart
var arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
var filter = arr.where( (name) => name != 'messi' );

// then
arr.clear();
arr.addAll(filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where method on lists returns a variable with type `WhereIterable<String>`. You can see it by running the following code:

```
 void main() {
   dynamic arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
   arr = arr.where((name) => name != 'messi');
   print(arr.runtimeType); // WhereIterable<String>
 }
```

When you wrote `var arr` List became the type and as Dart is a strictly-typed language, you can't assign a value of type `x` to a variable of type `y`, unless one of them is dynamic. The `dynamic` type means that it can take any type, like any in TS. So you have to call `toList()` on arr to convert it from iterable to a list:

```
 void main() {
   var arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
   arr = arr.where((name) => name != 'messi').toList();
   print(arr); // [mo salah]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `retainWhere`, result: `[no salah]`

```
List<String> x = ["messi", "no salah"];
x.retainWhere((f) => f != "messi");
print(x);
```

Your code will create a new list, but this code will update your list. You can choose which is useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question while I'm writing it here,

what I was missing? is or the difference between `filter` in **TS/JS** and `where` in **dart** that filter return `array` type but `where` is not and I have to convert it to an array by adding `toList()` at the end.

So my final code in dart should look like this:

```dart
var arr = ['messi', 'mo salah'];
arr = arr.where( (name) => name != 'messi' ).toList();

// results
// arr = ['mo salah'];
```